# How do previous Activation Map in CNNs affect the next Activation Map

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Say I have a `CNN` with **2** `layers`. to consume a picture of **25x25** `RGB` pixels, the `first layer` has `filter-size` = 50,`kernel size` = **5x5**, `stride` = **1x1** `padding` = **0x0**. and the `second layer` has the same parameters except that `filter-size` = **100**. Now I know that my `Activation Map` from the `1st layer's pass` is **21x21x3** in dimension (the **×3** is due to `RGB`).and this means I have **50** `activation maps` of **21x21x3** created via applying **50** different `filters` on the input picture.

My question is for the `second pass` since my `filter-size` = **100** does that mean that the **50** `activation maps` from `layer 1` are passed  through the **100** `filters` of the `second layer` each as `receptive fields` so that at the `second pass` I have a total of **100x50** `activation maps` or are the **50** `activation maps` fused into a single unit before being passed such that the `2nd layer` only produces **100** `activation maps` still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight misconception here. Instead of keeping the dimensions from your input image (in your case 3, since RGB), it does convolve *across all of them*. Meaning the output of your convolution operator `C` for a specific image region `x` of size `5x5x3` would be only a single value, not a vector of size `1x3`.

The activation maps (i like to call them feature maps) then simply imply *how many different convolutional filters you have*, and thus you get as many "output dimensions" stacked. In your example, the output would not be `21x21x3`, but instead `21x21x50`. 
For the next layer, you would similarly take an input of (I'm assuming you are using the same kernel size) `5x5x50`, and again produce only a single value. This time, you have 100 output stacks, so the resulting size would be `17x17x100`.

Comment: `@dennlinger` If I correctly understand you, since my image is RGB the dimension of the 50 filters applied during the 1st pass would be 5x5x3 each and not 5x5 to give 50x21x21 and not 50x21x21x3, and for the 2nd pass since we have 50 feature maps the filter dimension would be 50x5x5 to give a single element for each of the 100 feature maps. So the number of the previous feature maps produced is always the depth of the filter dimension for the next pass?

Comment: Exactly. The total size of all filters of the first layer together is thus 5x5x3x50.